# Return value from Stored Procedure is always null in delphi

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi, stored-procedures

I've got a small issue with delphi/sql server. I have a SP

```
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_adaugaUser]    Script Date: 6/30/2014 12:33:52 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_adaugaUser]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @User varchar(50), 
    @Password varchar(32)--,
   -- @errMesaj varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
declare @sUser varchar(50),
        @sPassword varchar(32),
        @errMesaj varchar(100),
        @exists bit, 
        @exists2 bit;
set @sUser = LTRIM(RTRIM(@User))
set @sPassword = LTRIM(RTRIM(@Password))


    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select @exists =  COUNT(*) from sys.server_principals where name = @sUser
    select @exists2 = COUNT(*) from sys.database_principals where name = @sUser
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    if @exists = 1 begin 
         if @exists2 = 1 set @errMesaj = 1 --'Userul deja exista'  
              else begin 
               exec ('CREATE USER [' + @sUser + '] FOR LOGIN [' + @sUser + ']') 
               set @errMesaj = 2  --'S-a creat userul pentru login deja existent'
               end
                   end
          else begin
                         exec(' CREATE LOGIN [' + @sUser  + '] WITH PASSWORD = ''' +@sPassword + '''
                                 CREATE USER [' + @sUser + '] FOR LOGIN [' +  @sUser+']')
                        set @errMesaj = 3 --'S-a creat user si login'
                        end

 RETURN @errMesaj   
END
```

This SP add a login and a user into a server/database... and returns a message based on what it has done.

In delphi I've got a TADOStoredProcedure that has 3 parameters :

1 : @User - ftString , pdInput
2 : @Password - ftString , pdInput
1 : @errMesaj - ftString , pdReturnValue

I call the TADOStoredProcedure  like this :

```
procedure TdataModule1.AdaugaUser(user, password : string );  // procedura ce apeleaza o SP din BD pentru adaugarea de useri
begin
   sp_adaugaUser.Parameters.ParamByName('@User').Value := user;
   sp_adaugaUser.Parameters.ParamByName('@Password').Value := password;
   sp_adaugaUser.Prepared :=  true ;
   try
   sp_adaugaUser.ExecProc;
   finally
   sp_adaugaUser.Prepared :=  false ;
   sp_vizualizare_useri.Close;
   sp_vizualizare_useri.Open;
   test := sp_adaugaUser.Parameters.ParamByName('@errMesaj').Value;
   end;

end;
```

but for some reason when I debug the value of test is always `null`, why?

Error : [image]

Comment: do you get an exception? It seems the executing user dont have the privilege to create a login or user

Comment: I've got the permision, i'm 100% as i'm connecting to SQL with sa user. I updated the post with a picture of error.

Comment: I'm actually surprised if SQL Server allowed you to alter your stored procedure as above. I would have expected an error message because RETURN is supposed to return an integer value - not varchar.

Comment: @Craig Young Why is that? It works fine for examen if I do : declare result varchar(30) exec result = sp_adaugaUser 'x' , 'y' print result. It works very well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use the parameter @errMesaj as described you will have to define it with [OUTPUT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004(v=sql.105).aspx).

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_adaugaUser]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @User varchar(50), 
    @Password varchar(32),
    @errMesaj varchar(100) OUTPUT
AS
```

The RESULT value of SQLServer procedure is limited to an integer [Return Data from a Stored Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx)

An example to show the different possibilies could look like this:

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_adaugaUser]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @User varchar(50), 
    @Password varchar(32),
    @errMesaj varchar(100) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
declare @sUser varchar(50),
        @sPassword varchar(32),
        @ReturnCode int,   
        @exists bit, 
        @exists2 bit;
set @sUser = LTRIM(RTRIM(@User))
set @sPassword = LTRIM(RTRIM(@Password))


    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select @exists =  COUNT(*) from sys.server_principals where name = @sUser
    select @exists2 = COUNT(*) from sys.database_principals where name = @sUser
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    if @exists = 1 begin 
         if @exists2 = 1 
            begin
              set @errMesaj = 'Userul deja exista'  
              set @ReturnCode = 1
            end
              else begin 
               exec ('CREATE USER [' + @sUser + '] FOR LOGIN [' + @sUser + ']') 
                 set @errMesaj = 'S-a creat userul pentru login deja existent'
                 set @ReturnCode = 2
               end
                   end
          else begin
                        exec(' CREATE LOGIN [' + @sUser  + '] WITH PASSWORD = ''' +@sPassword + '''
                                 CREATE USER [' + @sUser + '] FOR LOGIN [' +  @sUser+']')
                        set @errMesaj = 'S-a creat user si login'
                        set @ReturnCode = 2
                        end

    Return @ReturnCode
END
```

the minimal delphi code for a call

```
   sp_adaugaUser.Parameters.ParamByName('@User').Value := user;
   sp_adaugaUser.Parameters.ParamByName('@Password').Value := password;
   sp_adaugaUser.ExecProc;
   Showmessage(sp_adaugaUser.Parameters.ParamByName('@errMesaj').Value);
   Showmessage(IntToStr(sp_adaugaUser.Parameters.ParamByName('@RETURN_VALUE').Value));
```

using a TAdoStoredProc for sp_adaugaUser your parameters should look like this

[image]  [image]

the error you are getting is because in
`test := sp_adaugaUser.Parameters.ParamByName('@errMesaj').Value;` the value is NULL which can't be converted to a string.

Comment: I get the same error... even if I add @errMesaj as OUTPUT variable in SQL.

Comment: Just omitt `RETURN @errMesaj`  the result value is expected to be an integer.

Comment: Don't you have to include the OUT in the query which calls the sp as well?

Comment: @MartinA Delphi will declare it as `pdInputOutput` if you are using TStoredProc

Comment: @bummi I don't follow your comment, can you be more specific. Why should I delete the RETURN statement? Also if I use integers as returned values I get the same error. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @CiucaS I did an edit to make it more clear, what are the different options you are having.

Comment: Thank you, i'lloyd check it tomorrow and comentariu with a feedback.

Comment: @bummi i've tried your way ( btw I know I get my error becouse delphi tries to assign aq null value to a string ) but it doesn't work becouse, all these functions are build into a datamodule ( which has no showmessage procedure) also I have to asign the returned string/integer to a string/integer variable so I can move it to my form class.

Comment: @bummi it works now, the problem was the order of the parameters, as I had User, Password,errMesaj,RETURN_VALUE and RETURN_VALUE should have been the first one.